# MySQL 5.5 IF exists THEN syntax issue

Tags: mysql, if-statement, mysql-5.5

I am trying to wrap some logic checks in some old company MySQL 5.5 code:

For example,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <table_a> (
blah blah blah
);
```

I am trying to add a logic so that the query will only be executed when another table exists:

```
If <table_b> EXISTS

THEN

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <table_a> (
blah blah blah
);

END IF;
```

Here is my query following the MySQL 5.5 syntax (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html)

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT table_name 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
           WHERE table_schema = 'table_b_database'
             AND table_name = 'table_b')


THEN

       CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <table_a> (
    blah blah blah
    );

END IF;
```

Sadly there is an error message:

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Could any gurus enlighten?  Thanks.

Comment: MySQL only supports the `if` statement in programming blocks, such as stored procedures, functions, and triggers.

Comment: Instead of using a stored procedure, look at the result of each statement executed to see if it did anything.

Comment: each statement does well when run separately, but putting together just returns error messages like mentioning in the post.